# Office 2013 AddIn incompability on Windows 8.1

Tags: ms-office, add-in, office-addins, office-2013, comaddin

I have an Office 2013 COM AddIn which runs fine at Windows 7 Prof. but on Windows 8.1 it doesnt show up. Both machines have Office 2013 installed.

When I check the AddIn-Options on the 8.1 machine I find my COM AddIn under active AddIns (location: mscoree.dll, type: COM Add In)

But the AddIn, which extends the backstage menu by one tab, doesnt show up.

Are there any 8.1-specific options or other things I have to consider?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't matter what OS is used. Did you try to debug the add-in? Do you get any exceptions in the code?

Also I'd recommend checking for any UI errors. See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.